# Token based authorization implementation in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth

let me first set the stage with the cast of characters:

1. An MVC 5 application
2. A WebAPI

I need to implement a token based security to access #2 from #1.

What I have already:

1. Created a startup class in #2

   ```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
       // token generation
       app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
       {

          AllowInsecureHttp = true,

          TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
          AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),

          Provider = new MyServerProvider()
       });

       // token consumption
       app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
       var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
       WebApiConfig.Register(new HttpConfiguration());

       app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
   }
   ```

Standard code available everywhere on the internet.

1. This is the code in MyServerProvider also in #2

   ```
   public class MyServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
   {
       public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
       {
           context.Validated();
           await Task.FromResult(0);
       }

       public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
       {
           if (context.UserName == "one" && context.Password == "two")
           {
               var id = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
               id.AddClaim(new Claim("name", context.UserName));
               id.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

               context.Validated(id);
           }
           else
           {
               context.Rejected();
           }

           await Task.FromResult(0);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And another class that provides the token also in #3

   ```
   public class TokenProvider
   {
       public TokenResponse _tokenValue { get; set; }
       public  string _accessToken { get; set; }

       public string GetToken(string tokenEndpoint, string userName, string password)
       {
           var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(tokenEndpoint));
           var tokenResponse = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(userName, userName).Result;

           _tokenValue = tokenResponse;
           _accessToken = _tokenValue.AccessToken;

           return _accessToken;
       }
   }
   ```

So far so good.

Q1. Now when a request from a controller hits the api or the api is
    called form JavaScript, what happens? 
Q2. Which method from the
    above get's called?

Q3. What does GrantResourceOwnerCredentials do?

Q4. What does the context object in the above question has and how
    does one add the userName and Password to it and how are claims store in a cookie?

Q5. If I have to store the token in a cookie and use it for subsequent requests, do I write
    that code in OnActionExecuting method of the controller in #1?

This all may sound very specific but it isn't. I am trying to understand token based authentication from a real world scenario and I am new to this.

I have gone through the samples at ThinkTecture Github repo and they all do a good job in explaining them but I am stuck at implementing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Did you get anywhere.  I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Aaron found some really useful info [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/simple-oauth-server-implementing-a-simple-oauth-server-with-katana-oauth-authorization-server-components-part-1). Additionally I created a common controller with Auth key generation and other stuff which works. Let me know if you want more info on what I did will mail you that. Can't put that as an answer to this post.